# Ttcp specific question

Tags: tcp, testing

A TCP server has IP address 10.0.7.2 and a TCP client has IP address 10.0.7.3. The TCP server is waiting on port number 3333 for a connection request. The client connects to the server and transmits 2000 bytes to the server, which are sent as 4 write operations of 500 bytes each.

So I was wondering if were to write out this command for the receiver would this be correct?

```
ttcp -ts -l500 -n4 -p3333 -D 10.0.7.2
```

or would it be

```
ttcp -ts -l2000 -n4 -p3333 -D 10.0.7.2
```

I'm assuming that it would be the first option but am not confident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the server in Receive mode (i.e. `-r` option).  Try the below command syntax.

```
ttcp -r -s -p 3333 -D
```

Check out the [ttcp man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ttcp) for more details.

---

### Further reading

In order to make this a viable setup, you need a sender and receiver.  The sender effectively establishes all of the prameters the tcp session will be benchmarked on.

***Transmit***

```
ttcp -t [-u] [-s] [-p port] [-l buflen] [-b size] [-n numbufs] [-A align] [-O offset] [-f format] [-D] [-v] host [<in]
```

***Receive***

```
ttcp -r [-u] [-s] [-p port] [-l buflen] [-b size] [-A align] [-O offset] [-f format] [-B] [-T] [-v] [>out]
```

Take notice that the receiver is only modifying parameters the sender is specifying.  Initially, you were trying to:

```
-t Transmit mode.
-s stdout.
-l length 
-n number of source buffers
-p port
-D Do not buffer data when sending
```

As a receiver, you aren't allowed to use, or shouldn't be using, options `-t`, `-n`, or `-D`.